# Get top 3 highest values from array with index

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array containing doubles. Now I want to get the 3 highest values from the array and I want to know what are their indexes.

This is my code:

```
var threeHighest = wineOfferCounter.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3).ToArray();
var firstIndex = wineOfferCounter.ToList().IndexOf(threeHighest[0]);
var secondIndex = wineOfferCounter.ToList().IndexOf(threeHighest[1]);
var thirdIndex = wineOfferCounter.ToList().IndexOf(threeHighest[2]);

Console.WriteLine("Offer " + firstIndex + " bought " + threeHighest[0] + " times");
Console.WriteLine("Offer " + secondIndex + " bought " + threeHighest[1] + " times");
Console.WriteLine("Offer " + thirdIndex + " bought " + threeHighest[2] + " times");
```

but when the `wineOfferCounter` contains two or more values which are the same I get the first index twice. Instead I want to get unique indexes. So if at position `wineOfferCounter[3]` the value is 25 and at `wineOfferCounter[6]` the value is also 25. The result is:

```
"Offer 3 bought 25 times"
"Offer 3 bought 25 times"
```

But I want:

```
"Offer 3 bought 25 times"
"Offer 6 bought 25 times"
```

Comment: When you have more than one value, which index do you want? Say your list is [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]. So 3 max values are 3, 4, and 5. For 3 and 5, do you want the first index of occurrence, or else, which index?

Comment: Not maximally efficient, but uncomplicated: map to [value, index] pairs, sort, read the last three.

Comment: @Sach Yes, the first occurence is good. I need to avoid getting the same offer.

Comment: Try following threeHighest.First(), threeHighest.Skip(1).First(), threeHighest.Last()

Comment: You answer is wrong due to usage of `IndexOf`, which always results in the first Index, ideally you could have used a logic to skip the index already been read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a temp class with index and value and then sort by this class members. Something like this code:

```
var result = wineOfferCounter
    .Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.v)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.i)
    .Take(3)
    .ToArray();
```

then iterate through this collection:

```
foreach (var entry in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Offer " + entry.i + " bought " + entry.v + " times");
}
```

Comment: Oh well, you beat me to it. Nice concise answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or without having to make a simple class for this you could use a Tuple:

```
var threeHighest = wineOfferCounter
            .Select((offerTimes, index) => new Tuple<int, double>(index, offerTimes))
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2)
            .Take(3)
            .ToArray();

foreach (var offer in threeHighest)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Offer " + offer.Item1 + " bought " + offer.Item2 + " times");
}
```

Comment: Good solution but you are making it complex by using `Tuple`, which is not required

Comment: What is it about a tuple that makes it complex? Looking at OP's question, there doesn't seem to be a need to have a dedicated class for an offer since all he is doing is reading an index and value from an array. A tuple makes the data transfer very simple without having to make any more classes.

Comment: Look at the accepted solution and then decide. Accessing via item prefix itself is error prone and simply not required. It's not about class but simple data projection